# Deleting a newline in python if line beggines with a letter

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a little code/whatever to help me editing epg at work.
For example, if a multiple line epg is something like:

```
00:10\nNews \n
00:15\nSport news
```

i need to print them like this 00:10 News and 
                              \n 00:15 Sport news

I've tried multiple ways using rstrip and some regex but still suck, I want to know how to delete a `\n` when a new line begins with a letter.
Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Edit

Sorry for not replying yesterday, I tried a different way but still can't understand what is wrong with it:

```py
 new_lines = []
 lines = '\n10:10 \nsport \n10:15 \nworld news'
 for line in lines:
  if line[0].isdigit():
   line = line.strip()
   new_lines.append(line)
 ctt = (new_lines.append(line)
) print (ctt) i'm getting none output
```

Comment: please format your expected output properly and also share the output of your script

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the line of:

```
re.search('\n[a-zA-Z]', your_str)
```

Maybe you'll also want to look at `re.MULTILINE`

Comment: I don't think that completely answers the OP's question, which is good because he should be given an opportunity to try to find a solution for himself.